# How to Fix error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on c# class everything working fine.But inside some part of code its thrown an error like...
`"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."}"`

```
public void CreateConn()
{
   try 
   {
        if (constr.State == 0) 
        {
           //constr.ConnectionString = strConnString
           constr.ConnectionString = strConnString.ToString();
           constr.Open();
        }
   } 
   catch (Exception exp) 
   {
        throw exp;
   }
}
```

Comment: Show your connection string.

Comment: review your connectionString

Comment: SqlConnection strConnString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

Comment: @user3501237: can you show us your configuration file where your `connectionstring` is defined?

Comment: <add name="RegistrationConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=;Initial Catalog=whitelevel;User Id=;Password=" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: @user3501237: you need to specify the `Data Source` in your `connectionstring` ,if your database is stored in your localmachine specify dot as -> `"Data Source=.;`

Comment: @user3501237 Instead of using `strConnString.ToString()` you could have used `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionStri‌​ng"].ConnectionString`