# How to fix this error 'covert 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection' to 'string''

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am working on a C# class. Everything is working fine except this error:

> Convert 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection' to 'string'

So give me response to fix this error.

Code:

```
public void CreateConn()
{
    try 
    {
        if (constr.State == 0) 
        {
             constr.ConnectionString = strConnString;
             constr.Open();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception exp) 
    {
        throw exp;
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
constr.ConnectionString = strConnString;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `strConnString` is declared as a string?

Comment: SqlConnection strConnString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

Comment: And that the problem, strConnString is a SqlConnection not a string

Comment: so how to fix this error please give me the response.

Comment: In your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168333/how-to-fix-error-format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specif, which you left open by the way, you use the same code, but with strConnSTring.ToString(), you probably need strConnString.ConnectionSTring, but please direct further additions to that question to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string returned by your ConfigurationManager

```
public void CreateConn()
{
    if (constr.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
    {
         constr.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                                    ["RegistrationConnectionStri‌​ng"].ConnectionString;
         constr.Open();
    }
}
```

The error in your code is trying to assign an instance of a SqlConnection to the ConnectionString property that is a simple string.
The variable `strConnString` has a misleading name and in this context is not needed at all.

Notice that I have removed the useless try/catch because you don't do anything with the exception and just rethrowing it simply destroy the stack information in the exception data.

Another thing to avoid (I think you could have problems to compile that code as is) is the use of the constant 0 to check against the connection state. You shuould use the appropriate enumeration